# Flex Item to have specific height even when empty content

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

I am currently using angular flexbox for the below code.

I would like to make the middle flex item (div, to be more specific) to have a specific height, even when its content is empty.

The solution should involve using purely flex properties to give the height, unless it is not possible.

```
<div fxLayout="column"  style="height:100vh">
  <header style="background-color: lightblue;" >
        Header
  </header>
  <div style="background-color: orange;"  >

  </div>
  <footer style="background-color: yellow"> Footer </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add fxFlex to it to give it an height, this should work because it is within a column div which has a fixed height (you can play around with the value within the fxFlex to suit your needs).

```
<div fxFlex="50" style="background-color: orange;">
</div>
```

You can also make use of fxFill on the same div to fill all available space:

```
<div fxFill style="background-color: orange;">
</div>
```

source: https://tburleson-layouts-demos.firebaseapp.com/#/docs

Comment: Sorry, i made a small amendment to my code. The middle div should not have fxLayout="row". to avoid confusion. Has updated my query to reflect this.

Comment: I try putting fxFlex and fxFill to the middle div as u suggested. Bt the middle div does not expand at all.  Perhaps, u can access the link i provided above to run and see the code. Then try apply your solution to my code. Click save, and provide me the URL for me to view your solution.

Comment: I think the jsfiddle you provided doesn't have flex layout installed, since it doesn't respond to any of the flex layout attributes. I dont see any of the flex layout classes appear on the elements either when I use inspect element.

Comment: you are correct. I realize the jsfiddle has no flex. No wonder no matter how i initially try all sorts of solutions, it just wont work.  haha... Anyway I move to another online code platform with the flex installed, and test it out. Yeah your solution works! Thanks.

Comment: Hi Bodhi, can i query what does the fxFill actually does? Based on my online reading, it states "Using 'fxFill' to fill available width and height of parent container.", but when i apply fxFill to the centre div, via the F12 developer chrome tool, i notice height="100%" is applied to the div.

Comment: I want to achieve 15% header height, 15% footer height, and the middle div to fill up remaining space (i.e 70%). 

In https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-flex-layout-practice-wssmuz, instead of hardcoding 70%, I use fxFill to the middle div. And surprise that the vertical scrollbar appear and i found out that the height of the middle div is now same as the parent element, which is not what i expected.

Comment: I think this is what you want: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-flex-layout-practice-5aqnzp?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Yes! Wau, never know  can use fxFlex without a value. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div fxLayout="column"  style="height:100vh">
  <header style="background-color: lightblue;" >
        Header
  </header>
  <div style="background-color: orange;" fxFlexFill>

  </div>
  <footer style="background-color: yellow"> Footer </footer>
</div>
```

The fxFlexFill directive should be used on elements within a fxLayout container and identifies the element whose width and height should be maximized